# Camerax output image quality not as good as default camera output

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am using CameraX latest version (1.3.0-rc01) in my app to create a custom camera. Targeted audience is using Samsung mostly. I have observed that the quality of image taken using my app is having less quality compared to device camera output image. I tried to add HDR, Resolution selector, Noice reduction, post capture image modifications etc. Nothing helped. Quality issue is more when its zoomed (2.0 - 3.0 etc) where as device camera output in same zoom level is way different. Attached the screenshots of images taken through app and device camera.
[image: Taken through app in 3.0 zoom]

[image: Taken through device camera]

Images taken though app camera is **not smooth** and looks bit **grainy**. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What if you try an earlier version of CameraX? e.g. version 1.2.3?